# Android SQLite Database - Not reading decimal part of float from database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my first SQLite database with a float.  I can't figure out why I am unable to store/retrieve the decimal parts of a float.

The database is defined as:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    // Create a string that contains the SQL statement to create the Nbmc device table
    String SQL_CREATE_NBMC_TEMP_DATA_TABLE =  "CREATE TABLE " + NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + NbmcContract.NmbcTempData._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_DATA_FLOAT + " REAL) ";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_NBMC_TEMP_DATA_TABLE);
}
```

I store floating point data in it from a service activity:

```
 private static double  lastSensorTempReading;
           // ============ TEMP ==================
            else if (UUID_SENSOR_FFF2.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                rxSensorDataType = FFF2_TEMP_CONST;
                descStringBuilder.append("Elapsed Time: " + timeFormat.format(timeDiff) + "\n");

            // temp comes in two bytes:  newData[MSB], newData[LSB]
            // temp = MSB + (0.1 * LSB)
            int iTempMsb_i = (int) newData[0] & 0xff ;
            int iTempLsb_i = (int) newData[1] & 0xff;
            lastSensorTempReading = (float)iTempMsb_i + (0.10 * (float)iTempLsb_i);

            Log.v("broadcastUpdate","Temp = " + lastSensorTempReading);

            // Add this data to the temp Db
            tempValues.put(NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, estimatedTime);
            tempValues.put(NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_DATA_FLOAT, lastSensorTempReading);
            newRowId = db_temp.insert(NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.TABLE_NAME, null, tempValues);
        }
```

And, when I use the Log.v to dump the value I think I am storing it looks correct (and it looks correct when I send it to the Main Activity via an intent).

```
V/broadcastUpdate: Temp = 33.3
```

However, when I read it back from the SQLite database in my MainActivity, I'm losing the part of the float/double that follows the decimal point but I'm not getting errors reported in the Logcat.

```
       sb.append(" ------------------- Temperature Data -------------------------\n");
        nbmcTempDbHelper = new NbmcTempDataDbHelper( this.getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase tmpDb = nbmcTempDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        c = tmpDb.rawQuery(" SELECT " + NbmcContract.NmbcTempData._ID + ", "
                + NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + ", "
                + NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_DATA_FLOAT +
                " FROM  "   + NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.TABLE_NAME  +
                " LIMIT " + MAX_RESULTS_RETRIEVED + " OFFSET " + 0, null);
        try {
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String tempRowId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NbmcContract.NmbcTempData._ID));
                        String tempTimeString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP));
                        double tempDataDbl = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_DATA_FLOAT));
                        Log.v("getEmailText", "Temp reading = " + tempDataDbl);
                        sb.append(tempRowId);
                        sb.append(DELIMITER);
                        sb.append(tempTimeString);
                        sb.append(DELIMITER);
                        sb.append(tempDataDbl);
                        sb.append(NEW_LINE);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            c.close();
            tmpDb.close();
        }

V/getEmailText: Temp reading = 30.0
V/getEmailText: Temp reading = 30.0
V/getEmailText: Temp reading = 30.0
V/getEmailText: Temp reading = 30.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
double tempDataDbl = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_DATA_FLOAT));
```

While you are saving a `Double` you are retrieving an `Integer`. Just change the line to

```
double tempDataDbl = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_DATA_FLOAT));
```

Unfortunately AFAIK there is no way to get type mismatch. If you read through [Data Types in SQLite](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) it says :

> In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container. The dynamic type system of SQLite is backwards compatible with the more common static type systems of other database engines in the sense that SQL statements that work on statically typed databases should work the same way in SQLite. However, the dynamic typing in SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional rigidly typed databases.

Since any container e.g. `INTEGER` or `REAL` in your case can hold any and all kinds of data types and not even the database knows which type it is reading.

Comment: Thanks Abbas.  Is there a way to get it to give me type-mismatch warnings similar to the -Wall flag in gcc?

Answer (score 0):

yes, dear
issue is  at fetch time You having some problem with your code.

```
 double tempDataDbl = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_DATA_FLOAT));
```

change it to

```
 double tempDataDbl = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NbmcContract.NmbcTempData.COLUMN_DATA_FLOAT));
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I can't believe how long I've overlooked that!  (Why doesn't it throw a warning about type-mismatch?)